# An array storing indexes, array storing values, combine into array[index,value]

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays, an index array and a value array-

```
indexArr = [2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 1, 3, 8, 9, 10, 9];
valueArr = [10, 10, 5, 13, 9, 2, 0, 1, 6, 0, 6];
```

I want to use the indexArr and valueArr together to make a third array. My method works if the number in the indexArr is not a duplicate-

```
for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
      indexArr.includes(i) ? newArr.push(valueArra[indexArr.indexOf(i)]) : newArra.push(0);
    }
```

My new array is now stored as follows-

```
newArr {0:0, 1:2, 2:10, 3:10, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:5, 9:13, 10:9 }
```

My desired output is to take into account those duplicates and add the values together so that it will read as follows-

```
newArr {0:0, 1:2, 2:10, 3:10, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:6, 9:25, 10:9 }
```

At the moment it only takes the first occurrence on the indexArr for numbers (8/9). Can someone help please as to how i would go around achieving the desired input?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the indexes in the `indexArr` to directly set the value in the result array.

The snippet below finds the [`max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) value in the index array, creates a [`new Array()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array) based on that value (`max + 1`) and [`fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)s it with zeros.

It then iterates over the `indexArr` using [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) which provides both the index (`i`) stored in the array and the iteration index (`j`). Using these two indexes it adds the values from the `valueArr` to the element at the relevant index in the result array.

```js
const
  indexArr = [2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 1, 3, 8, 9, 10, 9],
  valueArr = [10, 10, 5, 13, 9, 2, 0, 1, 6, 0, 6];

const
  max = Math.max(...indexArr),
  result = new Array(max + 1).fill(0);

indexArr.forEach((i, j) => {
  result[i] += valueArr[j]
})

console.log(...result);
// [ 0, 2, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 25, 9 ]
```

Comment: Cheers mate worked! upvoted but rep not high enough to take affect

Comment: For future reference: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)